# Using cURL to retrieve current build status in TeamCity

Tags: curl, teamcity

As a build step I'm trying to use the following command line code to retrieve the build status of the current build:

```
curl –u "%system.teamcity.auth.userId%:%system.teamcity.auth.password%" \
        "%teamcity.serverUrl%/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:%teamcity.build.id%/status"
```

When I perform this action locally, it works and returns back a status, eg. `FAILURE`

However, when I run this on the TeamCity Agent, I get the following feedback:

```
[15:11:21][Step 9/10]   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
[15:11:21][Step 9/10]                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
[15:11:21][Step 9/10]   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: –u
[15:11:21][Step 9/10] curl: (6) Could not resolve host: TeamCityBuildId=15124
[15:11:21][Step 9/10] 100    82    0    82    0     0   1536      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1536
[15:11:21][Step 9/10] "Authorization" header is not specified
[15:11:21][Step 9/10] To login manually go to "/login.html" page
[15:11:21][Step 9/10] Process exited with code 0
```

Which seems to me like it's falling over because of authentication. But why does that happen? I've specified access credentials, why isn't it using them properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: TeamCityBuildId=15124` indicates a parameter mismatch somewhere as your server isn't named `TeamCityBuildId=15124`.

Running `curl.exe -u "user:password" "http://thisdomaindoesnotexist/httpAuth/app/rest/b
uilds/id:1234/status"` gives me `curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'thisdomaindoesnotexist'`

Your curl command (with correct parameters) worked in TeamCity for me:

```
[21:11:57]Step 1/1: Test (Command Line)
[21:11:57][Step 1/1] Starting: C:\curl-7.45.0\bin\curl.exe -u username:password http://secret.cloudapp.net/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:1234/status
[21:11:57][Step 1/1] in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\316bb6a03438b498
[21:11:57][Step 1/1]   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
[21:11:57][Step 1/1]                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
[21:11:57][Step 1/1]   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
[21:11:57][Step 1/1]   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
[21:11:57][Step 1/1] 100     7    0     7    0     0     64      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    64
[21:11:57][Step 1/1] SUCCESS
[21:11:57][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 0
```

Comment: It seems like I must have made a typo somewhere, because after a lot of iteration, returning to the original `curl -u "%system.teamcity.auth.userId%:%system.teamcity.auth.password%" "%teamcity.serverUrl%/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:%teamcity.build.id%/status"` request is now working correctly for me as well!

Answer (score 0):

It work this key:

`--user login:password`

instead of:

`-u`

for `curl 7.45` on `Windows 10` for me.